# How to resolve errors of installing grunt-contib-uglify

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I was trying to install  the module grunt-contrib-uglify and ended up with the below error:

```
[james@linux tmp]npm install grunt-contrib-uglify --save-dev
npm WARN package.json example-project@0.1.0 No description
npm WARN package.json example-project@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json example-project@0.1.0 No README data
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify/-/grunt-contrib-uglify-0.4.0.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-contrib-uglify/-/grunt-contrib-uglify-0.4.0.tgz
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/maxmin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm ERR! Error: No compatible version found: chalk@'^0.4.0'
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.3.0","0.4.0"]
npm ERR!     at installTargetsError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:719:10)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:638:10
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:142:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "grunt-contrib-uglify" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd /export/home/james/tmp
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.15
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.5
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/maxmin
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /export/home/james/tmp/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Any clues what this is about ?

Comment: Can you show us your package.json file?

Answer (score 2):

Try as below:

```
 1) npm install -g grunt-cli
```

This will put the grunt command in your system path, allowing it to be run from any directory.

Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner! The job of the Grunt CLI is simple: run the version of Grunt which has been installed next to a Gruntfile. This allows multiple versions of Grunt to be installed on the same machine simultaneously.

```
 2) npm install grunt --save-dev
```

The easiest way to add Grunt and gruntplugins to an existing package.json is with the command npm install  --save-dev. Not only will this install  locally, but it will automatically be added to the devDependencies section, using a tilde version range.

for further assistance follow this link

http://gruntjs.com/getting-started

Comment: I already got grunt-cli and couple of other modules.. error happended only when i tried to install grunt-contrib-uglify

Comment: Try to install this npm in root directory.
     npm install -g grunt-contrib-uglify